# how to remove words less than 3 characters from the columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe and I want to remove all the stop words from my column

```
df
      tweets
0   hey good morning
1   hey good afternoon
2   hmm this is good.
```

Desired Output:

```
           tweets
    0     good morning
    1     good afternoon
    2     this good.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `str.replace`:

```
df.tweets.str.replace(r'\b(\w{1,3})\b', '')
```

```
0       good morning
1     good afternoon
2        this  good.
Name: tweets, dtype: object
```

Comment: Are there any ways I could automatically remove all stop words from my column other than replacing this way? maybe a package?

Comment: Look into `nltk`, that would definitely be more robust to remove stop words